# How to clear the web storage by hitting the button?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So here is my form. There are two buttons which are submit and reset. If the user answers the question correctly, the score will be increased. Otherwise the scoring will be reduced. So when I try to reset the score to 0, the users' score will be deducted. I have tried many possible answers.

```
    <body>
        <form action="" class="from" id="form">
            <h3 class="score" id="score">
                Score : 0 
            </h3>
            <h1 class="question" id="question">1 + 1</h1>
            <input type="text" class="input" id="input" 
            placeholder="Enter Your Answer" autofocus autocomplete="off"
            >
            <button class="button">Submit</button>
            <button class="reset" id="resetScore">Reset</button>
        </form>
        
        <script>
    const a = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    const b = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);

    // question declared
    const questionDisp = document.getElementById("question");
    // form declared
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    // input declared
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    // score declared
    const score1 = document.getElementById("score");
    // reset declared
    const reset = document.getElementById("resetScore");

    let score = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("score"));//JSON.parse to convert the string to number

    if (!score){
        score = 0;
    }

    score1.innerText = `Score : ${score}`;
    questionDisp.innerText = `What is ${a} + ${b} = `;

    // answer for question declared
    const answer = a + b;

    form.addEventListener("submit", ()=>{
        const userAns = +input.value //plus to convert string to number
        if (userAns === answer ){
            score++;
            ScoreUpdate()
        } else {
            score--;
            ScoreUpdate()
            showAlert()
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("resetScore").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("resetScore").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }

    function ScoreUpdate(){
        sessionStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(score))
    }

    function showAlert() {
        alert ("WRONG ANSWER");
    }

    function deleteScore(){
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: First of all you should do a e.preventDefault() if you are running any javascript code on submit event

Comment: form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
})

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar _"First of all you should do a e.preventDefault() if you are running any javascript code on submit event"_ - That statement is to general. If you don't want the "default behavior" (submit the form/redirect the page) to happen then stop it with `.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you just using html and css not React if you use e.preventDefault() you can't show score in current page.

Secondly you can't add reset button in your form because everytime your form send a submit your eventListener("submit") function will run.

You can remove your resetbutton and add a location.reload() method in your deleteScore function you can handle this situation.

Here try this.

```
  <body>
    <form action="" class="from" id="form">
      <h3 class="score" id="score">Score : 0</h3>
      <h1 class="question" id="question">1 + 1</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="input"
        id="input"
        placeholder="Enter Your Answer"
        autofocus
        autocomplete="off"
      />
      <button class="button">Submit</button>


    </form>
    <button class="reset" id="resetScore">Reset</button>


    <script>
      const a = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
      const b = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);

      // question declared
      const questionDisp = document.getElementById("question");
      // form declared
      const form = document.getElementById("form");
      // input declared
      const input = document.getElementById("input");
      // score declared
      const score1 = document.getElementById("score");
      // reset declared
      const reset = document.getElementById("resetScore");

      let score = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("score")); //JSON.parse to convert the string to number

      if (!score) {
        score = 0;
      }

      score1.innerText = `Score : ${score}`;
      questionDisp.innerText = `What is ${a} + ${b} = `;

      // answer for question declared
      const answer = a + b;

      form.addEventListener("submit", () => {
        const userAns = +input.value; //plus to convert string to number
        if (userAns === answer) {
          score++;
          ScoreUpdate();
        } else {
          score--;
          ScoreUpdate();
          showAlert();
        }
      });

      document
        .getElementById("resetScore")
        .addEventListener("click", myFunction);
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("resetScore").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
        deleteScore();
      }

      function ScoreUpdate() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(score));
      }

      function showAlert() {
        alert("WRONG ANSWER");
      }

      function deleteScore() {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        score = 0;
        ScoreUpdate();
        location.reload();
      }
      console.log(score);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. but there need to use onclick function on html tag button